# Saddle point in a non-convex objective function

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, symmetric-functions

I am investigating the following minimization problem as follows. It is the summation of two fractional functions that mirror each other around $(y_c,y_n)=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$:

$Min\ z(y_c,y_n)=\frac{{\beta }_c{y_c}^2+{\beta }_my_cy_n+{\beta }_n{y_n}^2}{h-r_cy_c-r_ny_n}+\frac{{\beta }_c{(1-y_c)}^2+{\beta }_m(1-y_c)(1-y_n)+{\beta }_n{(1-y_n)}^2}{h-r_c(1-y_c)-r_n(1-y_n)}$

Subject to

$0\le y_c\le 1$

$0\le y_n\le 1$

Note that parameters are practically defined in a way that $h-r_cy_c-r_ny_n>0$ is always valid, and all parameters $r_c$, $r_n$,\textit{ }${\beta }_c$, ${\beta }_m$, ${\beta }_n$\textit{ }and\textit{ }$h$\textit{ }are positive real numbers. During the investigation, I checked the roots of derivatives of the objective function:

$\frac{df(y_c,y_n)}{dy_c}=\frac{2{\beta }_cy_c+{\beta }_my_n}{h-r_cy_c-r_ny_n}+r_c\frac{{\beta }_c{y_c}^2+{\beta }_my_cy_n+{\beta }_n{y_n}^2}{{\ (h-r_cy_c-r_ny_n)}^2}-\frac{2{\beta }_c(1-y_c)+{\beta }_m(1-y_n)}{h-r_c(1-y_c)-r_n(1-y_n)}-r_c\frac{{\beta }_c{(1-y_c)}^2+{\beta }_m(1-y_c)(1-y_n)+{\beta }_n{(1-y_n)}^2}{{(h-r_c(1-y_c)-r_n(1-y_n))}^2}=0$

$\frac{df(y_c,y_n)}{dy_n}=\frac{2{\beta }_ny_n+{\beta }_my_c}{h-r_cy_c-r_ny_n}+r_n\frac{{\beta }_c{y_c}^2+{\beta }_my_cy_n+{\beta }_n{y_n}^2}{{(h-r_cy_c-r_ny_n)}^2}-\frac{2{\beta }_n(1-y_n)+{\beta }_m(1-y_c)}{h-r_c(1-y_c)-r_n(1-y_n)}-r_n\frac{{\beta }_c{(1-y_c)}^2+{\beta }_m(1-y_c)(1-y_n)+{\beta }_n{(1-y_n)}^2}{{(h-r_c(1-y_c)-r_n(1-y_n))}^2}=0$

While I see similar terms in each equation, I could not solve this system of two equations with two variables by hand. But Maple software solved it easily and gave me the answer for roots as $(y_c,y_n)=(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$. Via plots, I see that this point is a saddle point.

Is there any property, theorem, etc., to show why this point is a root for such a system of equations? Or how it can be obtained and whether it is the only root? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you mean you could generalize the objective function with two terms? If so, that's great! But your definition of z(x,y) is similar to one of the terms. Right? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again! I did not know about such complicated algorithms. Interestingly, I did not use any given data. Do you mean such algorithms even can find such a precise solution for a parametric/ analytical model?

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to understand through a simple example, to solve a system of *rational equations* (A):

$$
\frac{(x-1)(y-2)}{(x-3)} = 0
\quad \land \quad
\frac{(y-4)(x-3)}{(y-2)} = 0
$$

the general idea is to transform it into an equivalent system of *polynomial equations* (B):

$$
\small
(x-1)(y-2) = 0
\quad \land \quad
(y-4)(x-3) = 0
\quad \land \quad
(x-3)u-1 = 0
\quad \land \quad
(y-2)v-1 = 0
$$

The advantage is that we can now compute a *Gröbner basis* of these polynomials (C):

$$
x-1 = 0
\quad \land \quad
y-4 = 0
\quad \land \quad
2u+1 = 0
\quad \land \quad
2v-1 = 0
$$

which, in general, will be a triangular system of polynomial equations, i.e. the first equation will be in the variable $x$ only, the second in the variables $x,y$, the third in the variables $x,y,u$ and the fourth in the variables $x,y,u,v$. It's the generalization of the *Gaussian elimination method*.

So, systems (C), (B) are true for $\small (x,y,u,v)=(1,4,-1/2,1/2)$, i.e. system (A) for $(x,y)=(1,4)$.

---

In particular, if we want to consider a generalization of the system of equations subject of the topic:

$$
\small
w(x,y) := \frac{ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f}{gx+hy+i},
\quad \quad
z(x,y) := w(x-2j,y-2j) + w(2k-x,2k-y)
$$

$$
\nabla z(x,y) = (0,0)
\quad \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \quad
(x,y) = (j+k,j+k)
$$

in *Mathematica* we can calculate it almost instantaneously by writing:

```
w[x_, y_] := (a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 + d x + e y + f) / (g x + h y + i)
z[x_, y_] := w[x - 2 j, y - 2 j] + w[2 k - x, 2 k - y]
{zx, zy} = Grad[z[x, y], {x, y}];
Solve[{zx == 0, zy == 0}, {x, y}]
```

> {{x -> j + k, y -> j + k}}

or, wanting to implement the strategy just described:

```
{nzx, dzx} = NumeratorDenominator[Together[zx]];
{nzy, dzy} = NumeratorDenominator[Together[zy]];
polys = {nzx, nzy, dzx u - 1, dzy v - 1};
Simplify[GroebnerBasis[polys, {v, u, y, x}, CoefficientDomain->RationalFunctions]]
```

> {-j - k + x, -j - k + y, -1 + (i - (g + h) (j - k))^4 u, -1 + (i - (g + h) (j - k))^4 v}

where it's clear that the solution found with `Solve[]` is the only one allowed, as we wanted to prove. On the other hand, I have no idea how to do it by hand, as I find it a very daunting task!

Comment: Thanks a million for your efforts! It was fascinating and informative!